# Operaciones de arreglos dinámicos

Tags: c

Mi problema es que quiero hacer operaciones con sus direcciones de memoria, no logro identificar la manera correcta para hacer la suma de ellos(es lo que se ve en el código), en mi parecer creo que si funciona la lectura del arreglo.
Gracias de antemano.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main (){
        int i,tam,respSwitch;//Cambiar de nombre tam
        int *arreglo1;//Declaramos el primer arreglo
        int *arreglo2;//Declaramos el segundo arreglo
        int *suma;
        printf("Introduce el tamanio de los arreglos: ");scanf("%i",&tam);//tam1
        //Asignamos al arreglo de manera dinámica el total de elementos que tendra
        arreglo1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tam);//arreglo1, tam
        arreglo2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tam);//arreglo2, tam
        //suma=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*tam);
        printf("Ingrese cualquier valor del menu\n"
                "1)Leer los arreglos\n2)Sumar\n3)Restar\n4)Multiplicar\n5)Dividir\n6)Salir\n");
        do{
            printf("Ingrese la opcion que guste ");scanf("%i",&respSwitch);
            switch(respSwitch){
                case 1:
                    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                        printf("%p\n",arreglo1);
                        ++arreglo1;
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                        printf("%p\n",arreglo2);
                        ++arreglo2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
                        suma=&arreglo1+&arreglo2;
                        printf("%p \n",&suma[i]);
                        ++arreglo1;
                        ++arreglo2;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Ingrese un numero correcto\n");
            }
        }while(respSwitch!=6);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara la pregunta. Entiendo que te falla el `case 2`. ¿ Que resultados esperas obtener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La variable `arreglo1` reside en alguna parte de la memoria, digamos la dirección 0x021103:

```
dirección contenido
0x021102:   0x02344
```

Y contiene otra dirección: la de un arreglo de cinco enteros en la dirección de memoria 0x023444:

```
dirección contenido
0x023444: 01 02 03 04 05
```

entonces:

- &arreglo1 vale 0x021102. El operador "&" obtiene la dirección.
- arreglo1 contiene 0x023444.
- *arreglo1 vale 01. El operador "*" recupera lo apuntado por.

Entonces, cuando quieras operar con los valores apuntados, usas `*arreglo1`, asi:

```
int suma = *arreglo1 + *arreglo2;
```

Cuando usas

```
suma=&arreglo1+&arreglo2
```

estas sumando las direcciones de los arreglos, no los valores a los que apuntan. Además, lo haces dentro de un `for`, y siempre estás sumando los mismos valores. Tienes que hacer aritmética de punteros para recorrer el arreglo:

```
suma = *(arreglo1 + i) + *(arreglo2 + i)
```

Al sumar "i" al puntero obtienes el elemento i-esimo.

En este código queda resumido todo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int tam = 5;
    int *arreglo1; //Declaramos el primer arreglo
    int *arreglo2; //Declaramos el segundo arreglo
    
    //  Pedir memoria para ambos arreglos.
    arreglo1 = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int)*tam); //arreglo1, tam
    arreglo2 = (int*) malloc(sizeof (int)*tam); //arreglo2, tam

    //  Inicializar ambos arreglos con valores 11, 12, 13, ...
    int valor = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        *(arreglo1 + i) = valor++;
        *(arreglo2 + i) = valor++;
    }
    
    printf("dirección=%0xd, contiene=%0xd, apunta a=%d\n", &arreglo1, arreglo1, *arreglo1);
    //  arreglo1 = arreglo1 + arreglo2
    for (int i =0; i < tam; i++) {
        *(arreglo1 + i) += *(arreglo2 + i);
        printf("%d ", *(arreglo1 + i));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

produce (en mi máquina):

```
dirección=88b8d468d, contiene=bd9e8260d, apunta a=10
21 25 29 33 37
```